# VBA: Change highlight color (RGB not wbColor) with keyboard shorcut (MS Word 2013)

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, highlighting

I have this module in VBA assigned to a keyboard shorcut to change the color of highlight:

```
Sub RotateHighlightwbColor()
  Select Case Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex
    Case wdYellow
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdGray25
    Case wdGray25
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
    Case wdRed
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink 
    Case wdNoHighlight
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Case Else
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    End Select

End Sub
```

But instead of wbColor I want to use RGB color(more choices of color).

I could find a way to do it but it uses `Shading` instead of `Highlights`.

```
Sub RotateHighlightRGB()
Select Case Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor

    Case RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(1, 255, 1)
    Case RGB(1, 255, 1)
        Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Case RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Case Else
        Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Is there a way to use RGB color with `Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex` instead of using `Shading`?

Comment: Don't use colorindex, just use color. Also [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426369/excel-set-background-colour-of-cell-to-rgb-value-of-data-in-cell)

Comment: I have tried `Select Case Selection.Range.HighlightColor` and then `Selection.Range.HighlightColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)` (for instance), but VBA gives me an error: Compile error method or data member not found. I have tried with `Select Case Selection.Range.Interior.Color` (as suggested on your link, but it seems it's only working with excel not with word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer to "*Can we change the highlight color*" is  **No**.  The HighlightColorIndex must refer to an "Applies to" list of constants.  The set for the WdColorIndex constants (MSDN Word 2003) is …

**wdAuto
wdBlack
wdBlue
wdBrightGreen
wdByAuthor
wdDarkBlue
wdDarkRed
wdDarkYellow
wdGray25
wdGray50
wdGreen
wdNoHighlight
wdPink
wdRed
wdTeal
wdTurquoise
wdViolet
wdWhite
wdYellow**

This list is similar to an emuneration without the numbers, it is a set or collection that must be used with this particular limited property. There is no Highlight object that I have found referenced.

In the shading example given, the .shading "property" actually returns a shading object which can access the full RGB Color Model  as your code above demonstrates and is referenced many places including https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355244.aspx

The Office 2003 remarks for WdColorIndex explain the wdByAuthor entry in the list above.

*"If the InsertedTextColor property is set to **wdByAuthor**, Microsoft Word automatically assigns a unique color to each of the first eight authors who revise a document."*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.  See the [interior.color property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color).

for example:

```
    WB.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
```